# How do I interpret this git bisect output?

Tags: git

I ran `git bisect` to find an error in my code:

```
Frank:wdi user$ git bisect good 36c1756119c19d4773d008a7ba944f8a9cb35a18
9095710f3e59feb7ad2c8609f4877998e0b5c07c is the first bad commit
commit 9095710f3e59feb7ad2c8609f4877998e0b5c07c
Author: Eric Baldwin <email address>
Date:   Wed Aug 14 12:10:08 2013 -0400

    Commit message

:100755 100755 3502c3b66f26ed6c6031fb2c406933143418b887 efe4970775fb1b35525abfbd9da7ded8a8003d39 M  Gemfile
:100644 100644 f171121bb0cf5f5350636f032b07ebc3e643a271 d2fc157cf2bd0b26c7eac14a65fbd32b5fa5e312 M  Gemfile.lock
:040000 040000 771b9240530ad699dadad1ea3117754b1c927e0a 92659d3a5a4cee031435394f03049a8baa2e1209 M  app
:040000 040000 027677959fac0f3d0efca22c38e69000f19e7f9b eabdc7c09f6a8ef46d6e493bb3511a8c835e7f14 M  spec
```

I want to view the differences between the good versions of files and the bad versions of files to determine what exactly the error was.  How can I do that with this output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`git diff first_bad_commit_hash^ first_bad_commit_hash` will show you the diff between that first bad commit and the commit immediately prior to it.

In your case that'd be:

`git diff 9095710f3e59feb7ad2c8609f4877998e0b5c07c^ 9095710f3e59feb7ad2c8609f4877998e0b5c07c`

Comment: `git log -p -1 first_bad_commit` would be a reasonable alternative to this, as well...

Comment: I ended up using your `^` a lot over the past few hours.  This ws pretty helpful

Answer (score 1):

If you didn't, you should run `git bisect reset` to reset `HEAD` to where it was at the beginning.

Then, to see the diff between the first bad commit and the last good just use `git diff --color 9095710f3e59feb7ad2c8609f4877998e0b5c07c 36c1756119c19d4773d008a7ba944f8a9cb35a18`.

Comment: Note that you don't need to copy the entire hash -- the first few characters will do, so long as the result is unique in your repository.

Comment: @EricBaldwin It's unusual that you'd want to diff anything other than the first bad commit, and the commit immediately before it, because you want to see what changes were made in the bad commit that could have broken your code. [Danielle's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18274457/how-do-i-interpret-this-git-bisect-output/18274685#18274685) is thus the better approach.

Answer (score 1):

git says that the regression comes from the commit-id 9095710f3e59feb7ad2c8609f4877998e0b5c07c

so, you can view what has changed in 9095710f3e59feb7ad2c8609f4877998e0b5c07c with :

```
git show 9095710f3e59feb7ad2c8609f4877998e0b5c07c
```

or what differs from actual HEAD with

```
git diff 9095710f3e59feb7ad2c8609f4877998e0b5c07c HEAD
```

and so on..